# Busca aleatoria no listview através do editext em android?

Tags: android, listview, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro, edittext

Olá, sou bem novo em programação, na verdade entusiasta, veja só eu estou querendo tipo que o `editext` busque a letra ou palavra no texto de forma que por exemplo se na minha `string` estiver escrito "Sr. Jose Ventura" e eu digitar apenas "Ventura" esta possa ser localizada. Desde já obrigado, fico grato se postar o código.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private String[] lst;
private ArrayList<String> lst_Encontrados = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvlist);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlist);

    lst = new String[] {"Sr. José Ventura","Sra. Maria Cícera","Vô Antonio"};


    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst));
    CarregarEncontrados();


    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            CarregarEncontrados();


            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst_Encontrados));
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {


            AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Sr. José Ventura")){
                test.setTitle("test1");
                test.setMessage("0123456789");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();


            }
            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Sra. Maria Cícera")){
               test.setTitle("Sra. Maria Cícera");
                test.setMessage("486597231");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();
            }

            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Vô Antonio")){
                test.setTitle("Vô Antonio");
                test.setMessage("23456892");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();;;
            }


                       }
    });



}


public void CarregarEncontrados() {
    int textlength = et.getText().length();

    lst_Encontrados.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        if (textlength <= lst[i].length()) {
            String textoAux = (String) lst[i].subSequence(0, textlength);
            String textoFormatado = et.getText().toString();


            textoAux = removeAcentos(textoAux);

            textoFormatado = removeAcentos(textoFormatado);

            if (textoFormatado.equalsIgnoreCase(textoAux)) {
                lst_Encontrados.add(lst[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Map<Character, Character> acentosMap;

public static String removeAcentos(String texto) {

    if (acentosMap == null || acentosMap.size() == 0) {
        acentosMap = new HashMap<>();
        acentosMap.put('À', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Á', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Â', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Ã', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Ä', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('È', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('É', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Ê', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Ë', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Í', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ì', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Î', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ï', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ù', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ú', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Û', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ü', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ò', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ó', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ô', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Õ', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ö', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ñ', 'N');
        acentosMap.put('Ç', 'C');
        acentosMap.put('ª', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('º', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('§', 'S');
        acentosMap.put('³', '3');
        acentosMap.put('²', '2');
        acentosMap.put('¹', '1');
        acentosMap.put('à', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('á', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('â', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('ã', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('ä', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('è', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('é', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('ê', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('ë', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('í', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ì', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('î', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ï', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ù', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ú', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('û', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ü', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ò', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ó', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ô', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('õ', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ö', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ñ', 'n');
        acentosMap.put('ç', 'c');
        acentosMap.put('ç', 'c');
    }

    if (texto == null) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(texto);

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        Character c = acentosMap.get(sb.charAt(i));
        if (c != null) {
            sb.setCharAt(i, c);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: Qual o seu problema? O que tentou fazer?

Comment: Então sr. Jorge B. não sei bem usar o vocubulario de vcs usuarios avanzados, mas vou te explicar, esse codigo ai encima ta funcionando blza, so que tipo na minha string tem escrito "Sr. Jose Ventura" se eu digito apenas "Ventura" no edittex nao aparece "Sr. Jose Ventura" na lista, então o que eu estou buscando é algo que possa fazer com que mesmo se eu digitar palavras ou letras que estão no meio das frases ou palavras essas possam ser mostradas na busca. Deu pra entender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplesmente no meu carregaencontrados mudei o codigo por este e assim ele faz buscas no meio das palavras, espero ajudar:

```
 public void CarregarEncontrados() {
    int textlength = et.getText().length();

    lst_Encontrados.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        if (textlength <= lst[i].length()) {

            if (lst[i].toLowerCase().contains(
                    et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                lst_Encontrados.add(lst[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wilfer**, fiz algo parecido com isso esses dias, é um filter que permite buscar digitando dentro de um EditText.

Esse método você adiciona dentro do seu Adapter.

```
public Filter getFilter()
{
    Filter filter = new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence filtro)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (filtro == null || filtro.length() == 0)
            {
                results.count = listaProfdFiltrado.size();
                results.values = listaProfdFiltrado;
            } else
            {
                List<Produto> produtosFiltrados = new ArrayList<Produto>();

                for (int i = 0; i < listaProfdFiltrado.size(); i++)
                {
                    Produto produto = listaProfdFiltrado.get(i);

                    filtro = filtro.toString().toLowerCase();
                  //condicao, ean e plu alterar para os itens que deseja buscar
                    String condicao = produto.getDescricao().toLowerCase();
                    String ean = produto.getEan();
                    String codigoPlu = produto.getCodigo();
                   //apenas uma validação minha porque preciso buscar por 3 referencias
                    if (condicao.contains(filtro) || ean.contains(filtro) || codigoPlu.contains(filtro))
                    {

                        produtosFiltrados.add(produto);

                    } 
                }

                results.count = produtosFiltrados.size();
                results.values = produtosFiltrados;

            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
        {
            listaProdutos = (List<Produto>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    };
//retorna o filter do que você pesquisou
    return filter;

}
```

Dentro do seu onCreate você precisa inicializar seu componente, o metodo onTextChanged fica responsável por exibir as alterações que você faz quando digita.

```
   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            //o filtro é chamado para efetuar as operações
            adapterListView.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }
    });
```

**Nota**: Essas listas são do meu uso, você precisa trocar ou para um array simples ou trabalhar com o seu tipo de lista.

[Documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) onde trata do Filter

Comment: Vou tentar aqui pra ver se entendi o que escreveste acima, vê só eu terei que escrever o seu public filter abaixo do meu código ou terei que criar uma clase adapter só para ele? desde já obrigado e mil desculpas pois sou entusiasta de programação, não exite curso ou algo parecido ou moro assim vou na base do erro e acerto e conversando com vcs aqui! muito obrigado pela ajuda desde já! e tentando entender o que for escrito a adaptar a minha necesidade!

Comment: Não sei como está o seu projeto, seria ideal ter um adapter, mas se você ainda não chegou nesse nivel coloca abaixo do código, da uma olhada nos blogs de android muito tem exemplos de aplicações pequenas porém completas para você treinar, indico também o livro do Lecheta - Google Android, quando comecei ele andava comigo no café, almoço e janta. Qualquer dúvida posta aqui. @wilfer

Comment: Wellington Avelino, ainda sou novato, porem algumas coisas consigo entender outras não, entendo sobre logica de programacao, mas de linguagem em si me custa um pouco, então o adapter tenho ideia de como fazer, mas vou fazer como voce mandou e ver no que da!

Comment: Tentei copiar e colocar abaixo do meu codigo, algumas coisas soube como trocar os nomes já outras não segue abaixo oque não pude trocar:

Comment: List<Produto> produtosFiltrados = new ArrayList<Produto>();  não por que atributo meu devo mudar a palavra"produto" Produto produto = lst_Encontrados.get(i); e nem a palavra getdescricao String condicao = produto.getDescricao().toLowerCase(); e a getean e tambem getCodigo, desde ja muito obrigado

Comment: Apenas defini que os produtos filtrados vão ser uma lista de produtos

Comment: Uhum creio que a sua resposta seja otima e solucione meu problema, pena que não estou consiguindo entender a logica de como implementar seu codigo como  o meu, muito obrigado mesmo amigo pela ajuda! Que tudo esteja bem como vc e entes queridos sempre!

Comment: se não for muito incomodo para sua pessoa, será que você poderia me ajudar um pouco mais, tipo implementar seu codigo no meu codigo y copiar aqui? obs: sei que obviamente deves ser ocupado, aguardarei com prazer a sua ajuda.